# How to encapsulate stun binding request in Send indication in python

Tags: webrtc, stun, ice

I'm trying to send binding request to TURN/Relay server but have it encapsulated in Send Indication as a client would do when talking to TURN server to relay to a far end party.
Any pointers would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Your question seems to be very generic. Could you be more specific about your problem, and what solutions you have tried or researched. As it stands the questions is likely to be closed as off-topic because too generic and opinion-based (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This other link should help with question quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to implement a keep-alive message with the remote peer using STUN over TURN relay?

Comment: In ICE STUN packets are tunnelled from party A to party B via the TURN server.
For party a to send binding request to party B (behind the TURN server) it needs to encapsulate that request (using Send Indication) to the TURN server who will then unpack this before forwarding the request as Binding request to Party B.